# Explaination of this particular approach to form differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider we need to form differential equation of the following:

$Ax^2 + By^2 = 1$
where A & B are constants.

Now **one approach** I know of is two differentiate this equation 2 times (since 2 constants) and solve the problem by eliminating constants.

But I recently saw **another solution** of which I am looking for an explanation.

To solve the question, they set the wronskian to 0.

$
\begin{array}{|ccc|}
&x^2 &y^2 &-1 &\\
&2x &2yy' &0 &\\
&2 &2(y'^2+yy'') &0 &\\
\end{array} = 0
$

My question is how can we be sure that the determinant is zero? Is there some condition I am missing? Can we apply it for forming any differential equation?

Comment: The set of equations $$Au_i+Bv_i=w_i\qquad i=1,2,3,$$ has a solution if and only if they are proportional in the sense that there exist a nontrivial zero linear combination of $(u_i)$, $(v_i)$, $(w_i)$, which happens if and only if the determinant $$\left|\begin{array}{ccc}u_1&v_1&w_1\\ u_2&v_2&w_2\\ u_3&v_3&w_3\end{array}\right|$$ is zero. Hence the "determinant" method is equivalent to the elimination method you first describe.

Comment: Can you please explain more on that. or any link to read more about this?

Comment: The WP page on determinant, perhaps?